# What is the difference between abstractclass(metaclass=ABCMeta) and class abstractclass(ABC) in Python ABC module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, abc

I have seen two ways for defining Abstract Classes in Python.

This one:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
class AbstactClass(metaclass = ABCMeta):
```

And this one:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class AbstractClass2(ABC):
```

What are there differences between them and what are the respective usage scenarios?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no actual functional difference. The `ABC` class is simply a convenience class to help make the code look less confusing to those who don't know the idea of a metaclass well, as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) states:

> A helper class that has ABCMeta as its metaclass. With this class, an
> abstract base class can be created by simply deriving from ABC
> avoiding sometimes confusing metaclass usage

which is even clearer if you look at the the implementation of [abc.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/abc.py#L184), which is nothing more than an empty class that specifies `ABCMeta` as its metaclass, just so that its descendants can inherit the type:

```
class ABC(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """Helper class that provides a standard way to create an ABC using
    inheritance.
    """
    __slots__ = ()
```